# Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this piece of code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I want to check if the length of the string is >3 and if there are more than two spaces.
I implemented a for loop to count how many spaces are there(code below).
Then used the 'if'.
When I add &&, the app crashes when there are less than 3 characters.
It works when I remove the && part but, I need it! :/
Is it a problem with the logic I have used? :/

for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        if(message.charAt(i) == ' '){
              count++;
        }
}
```

then the if part:

```
if(message.length()<3 && count>2){
     outputText.setText("Duh! DO NOT TRY TO FIGURE THIS OUT!");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"WARNING!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
     methodEncrypt(message);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``i < message.length`` rather than ``i < 4``?

Comment: Many problems! it is complicated to help. First, `Encrypt method (message);` is it a recursive call? Post the complete code, please!

Comment: "Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this piece of code in Android Studio?" this doesn't really help anyone to understand what your question is about, it's best to make it as specific as possible

Answer (score 2):

NomadMaker is correct. One reason the loop may be failing is the assumption that the length of 'message' is greater than 4. If message = '123', then attempting to get the 'charAt' index 4 will fail due to the requested index being greater than the size of the String.

Updating to:

```
for(int i=0; i < message.length(); i++)
{
        if(message.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
              count++;
        }
}
```

Should resolve this issue. Some minor performance improvements may also be considered. Ex:

1. If the length of the String is less than 4, don't bother iterating through the String.
2. Once the second space is found, don't bother iterating through the rest of the String.